# Using custom selectors in Jquery

Tags: jquery

My code programmically creates `<span>` nodes with a custom ID. I am trying to access a specific one using Jquery but it doesn't want to work for me.

the html:

```
 <div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <span id="menu">
        </span>
        <center></center>
        <span id="refresh" runat="server">
        </span>
    </div>
    <div id="content" runat="server">
    <ul id="list" runat="server"></ul>
    </div>
    <div id="article" runat="server">
    </div>
</div>
```

the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").click(function () {
        var post = $(this).data('postid'); //this works and returns the postID selected.
        $('#list').slideUp(); //this hides all the anchor tags
        $('#' + 'post' + post).show(); //This is what is not working
    });
});
```

the .net c#

```
    foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
    {
        subject[count] = item.Title.Text;
        date[count] = item.PublishDate.DateTime.ToString();

        summary[count] = item.Summary.Text;
        list.InnerHtml += "<a href=\"#\" data-postid=\"" + count +"\"><li id=\"post" + count + "\"><span id=\"bold\">" + subject[count] + "</span><br>" +
           "<span id=\"posted-date\">Posted on: " + date[count] + "</span></li></a>";
        article.InnerHtml += "<span style=\"display: none;\" class=\"post\" id=\"post" + count + "\">" + summary[count] + "</span><br>";
        count++; 
    }
```

Pretty much when I click one of the anchor nodes, it grabs the postID and hides the list of anchor tags I have and is suppose to display(un-hide) the post that has the postID.

Please let me know if u need any more information.

Comment: Is the postID a number? Can you show the HTML for the link?

Comment: What is the value of the `var post` you are getting?

Comment: if you add `alert("post = " + post);` at line 4 do you get what you are expecting?

Comment: What does `console.log('#' + 'post' + post)` show?  How about `console.log($('#' + 'post' + post).length)`?

Comment: Note: `postID` is not a valid attribute for an anchor tag

Comment: Each postID span node is getting created by an array of items. There are 9 items in the array so right now its 0-8, I have a value incrementing everytime it goes through the foreach loop and I use that count variable to append the post id.

Comment: Even though not related, your html is invalid you should use custom attributes prefixed with data-* and you can access it as `$(this).data('postID')`

Comment: @billyonecan I read somewhere HTML5 supports it.

Comment: I think you should try to avoid the use of custom attributes like `postID`.What if someday html introduces an attribute with the same name?? Instead you should use `data-ATTR_NAME`. You can take a look at this [link](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/)

Comment: The spans aren't contained in the `#list` element are they?

Comment: You are not showing your complete html. i assume your span is not inside the div #list

Comment: @Luca the element you're trying to show isn't inside of `#list` is it?

Comment: The list is in a div called "list" where the posts are in a div called "article"

Comment: Another thing again not related. If you are targeting a span with an anchor and it is one-one why can you use <a data-postID="#post0"/> and just say `$($(this).data('postID')).show()` avoid string concatenation...

Comment: @Luca Can you edit your question and provide the full markup?

Comment: Just did a big edit with my code

Comment: @Luca you cannot duplicate `id's` - your `<li>` and `<span>` elements both have the `id="post" + count`

Comment: That was the problem. THANK YOU!!

Comment: @Luca no problem, glad you've solved it :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't duplicate element `id's`. Your `<span>` and `<li>` elements both use the id `"post" + count`, when you call `.show()` it'll only grab the first element matching this `id`, in this case the `<li>`

Answer (score 3):

Your ids aren't unique.

You've got `<li id=\"post" + count + "\">` and `<span style=\"display: none;\" class=\"post\" id=\"post" + count + "\">"`. Which will return something like `<li id="post42">` and 
`<span style="display: none;" class="post" id="post42">` where an id is used twice.

Make sure to use unique ids and the `show()` method will work.

Answer (score 0):

> Pretty much when I click one of the anchor nodes, it grabs the postID
>   and hides the list of anchor tags I have and is suppose to
>   display(un-hide) the post that has the postID.

Assuming the posts links are ordered the same as the posts themselves, do you really need the post ID? how about the following refactoring:

```
// The posts links

<ul class="posts_list"> 
    <li>Post Number 1 title</li>
    <li>Post Number 2 title</li>
    <li>Post Number 3 title</li>
    <li>Post Number 4 title</li>
</ul>


// the full posts

<ul class="posts"> 
    <li>Post number 1. bla bla bla</li>
    <li>Post number 2. bla bla bla</li>
    <li>Post number 3. bla bla bla</li>
    <li>Post number 4. bla bla bla</li>
</ul>
```

JQuery:

```
posts = $(".posts>li");

$(".posts_list").find("li").click(function(){

index = $("li").index(this);

posts.hide();
posts.eq(index).show();

});
```

[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/obegaw/3/)